# Material Table in Angular 5

Tags: material-design, angular-material2, angular5

I try to create a [basic material table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) in Angular 5.
But I always have the same error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: elementRef is undefined

This error come even when I leave `<mat-table></mat-table>` totally empty.

Here is my module:

```
import {NgModule, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MyComponent } from './my_component.component';
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';
import { MatCardModule, MatTableModule, MatInputModule, MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    FormsModule

  ],
  declarations: [
    MyComponent
  ]
})

export class MyComponentModule {
}
```

HTML, TS and SCSS are exactly the same than the [material tutorial](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview).

Comment: Why do you need a module just for one component?

Comment: because I need it to import MatTableModule, and other modules.

Comment: Can I have a stacktrace of it? It may help.